# htaccess redirect to non www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I have this code on my website so all the www request will be transferred to non www.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's working perfectly *BUT* I also want to include ANY page requested to the non www.

for example :

http://www.puaction.com/sitemap.xml

will be redirected to :

http://puaction.com/sitemap.xml

so any page requested will be redirected to non www

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: That is what your rule is already doing i.e. any www page requested will be redirected to non www.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://yourdomaine.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]